# Unable to access nested array of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following array of objects:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [original_price] => 1100
            [discounted_price] => 1100
        )
)
```

I am trying to access original and discounted price using javascript. But not getting.
I have tried `result[0]['original_price']` where result is the total result but not getting the value.

Comment: Are you sure this belongs under the `javascript` tag? That is a php array.

Comment: can you show the javascript object (not this pictogram )

Comment: This array I am getting as a result of ajax call, and I have to use javascript compulsary to access the same

Comment: You need to use `json_encode($array)` in your PHP code

Comment: Send from server as json_encode($array) & then use JSON.parse(arr) on client side.

Comment: @srikantamondal How do you make the ajax call? In some implementations, the actualy data is under `result.data`

Comment: @srikantamondal
1st  try to put a `console.log` on javascript and add the result here.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you returning array itself from ajax call? 
Instead you have to return an JSON Object like:

```
json_encode($array);
```

And then in your ajax response use it like:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
```

now use data accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In JS, you should use `array_name.object_name` format

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get this value in javascript then you can try with below way:

https://jsfiddle.net/ofvcahhr/

```
var arr = {};

arr[0] = {
          "origanl_price": 1100,
          "discounted_price": 100
          };

alert(arr[0].origanl_price);
```